# How do I show all values in a pivot table (instead of having repeat values grouped together)?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, pivot-table

[Here's a screenshot : )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYihx.png)I have a table with two columns: first name, last name.

Some people in the table share the same first name (e.g. David Simms and David O'Brien).

When I create a pivot table with first name as the first row and last name as the second, "David O'Brien" is shown in the Pivot Table, but only "Simms" is listed because David Simms is grouped under "David" (see attached screenshot).

How can I create a pivot table that shows David for both? My goal is to use the pivot table as a data source for further analysis (e.g. to plug into other functions) and if I can't pull "David" for "David Simms" then the Pivot Table isn't working the way I'd like it to.

Thanks!

I made the last name the first row of the pivot table and ran into the same problem since two people in the list have the same last name. Darn it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling the `Repeat row labels` setting

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How did I miss that?! Much appreciated